# How do I combine 2 string into 1 string with duplicated string pattern removed? C#

Tags: c#

I want to combine some strings that user input into 1 string, but if the end pattern of the first string is same as the start pattern of the second string, then remove the second one's start pattern and combine it into 1 string.

For example:

1. "apple" + "letter" + "man" 3 strings, output as "appletterman"
2. "helloworld" + "world" + "!" 3 strings, output as "helloworld!"

I just wrote the input part and I don't know how to continue the combine process.

```
        int size = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        string[] words = new string[size];
        string combinedWord = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            words[i] = System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
        // Combine the strings in words[i] to combinedWord here
        // which I don't know how to do it.
```

Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: Do you really mean "pattern" or must the entire next string match? For example, lots of words end in "e" and start with "e" and that would match the pattern but almost certainly not be what you want.

Comment: Yes, I mean that kind of "pattern".I know it's little bit strange to do something like that. It's just a practice for me to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do what youre looking for:

```
string MergeWords(string word1, string word2)
{
    for (int i = word2.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (word1.EndsWith(word2.Substring(0, i)))
        {
            return word1 + word2.Substring(i);
        }
    }

    return word1 + word2;
}
```

Basically,

It will iterate on the second word, taking first the entire word and then each iteration one less letter and checks if the first word ends with this pattern.

The above loop could be rewritten with LINQ: (i'll leave it up to you to decide which is more readable and clear)

```
string MergeWords(string word1, string word2)
{
    var index = Enumerable
                 .Range(0, word2.Length+1)
                 .First(i => word1.EndsWith(word2.Substring(0, word2.Length - i)));
    return word1 + word2.Substring(word2.Length - index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method tries to find longest match at the beginning of second string :

```
static string join(string a,string b)
{
    for (var i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
    {
        if (b.IndexOf(string.Join("", a.ToArray().Skip(i))) == 0)
        {
            return a + string.Join("", b.ToArray().Skip(a.Length - i));
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
string[] testArray = { "apple", "letter", "man" };
var result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Count(); i++)
{
    result = join(result, testArray[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
"appletterman"
```